# iterating of muliple items in jstl

Tags: jstl

I have this requirement to iterate over 3 lists at the same time in jstl. for iterating over a single list we use

```
<c:forEach var = "mfgn" items = "${requestScope.mfgNumber}" varStatus = "status">
    do something;   
</c:forEach>
```

I need to do some thing like

```
<c:forEach var = "mfgn" var = "issue" items = "${requestScope.mfgNumber}" items = "${requestScope.something" varStatus = "status">
     mfgNumber;     
</c:forEach>
```

is this possible or there an otherway to iterate over multiple lists at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

If they have the same size, then there are two options, assuming that it are `List<Integer>` and `List<String>`:

1. Merge them in a single list with entities which in turn repesents the items of each other list in a single class like `List<ManfacturerIssue>` where the `ManfacturerIssue` is a javabean class which contains `Integer number` and `String issue` properties. This way you can end up doing:

   ```
   <c:forEach items="${mfgIssues}" var="mfgIssue">
       ${mfgIssue.number}, ${mfgIssue.issue}
   </c:forEach>
   ```
2. Iterate by index instead, this is however ugly and unmaintainable as (fill in):

   ```
   <c:forEach begin="0" end="${fn:length(mfgNumbers) - 1}" varStatus="loop">
       ${mfgNumbers[loop.index]}, ${issues[loop.index]}
   </c:forEach>
   ```

Comment: Is it possible to write this as `generic` function ?  something  like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201778/writing-custom-functions-in-jstl