# Writing Custom Functions in JSTL

Tags: java, function, jsp, jstl

I am using jstl `C:forEach` to print the table in the jsp. I validate it like ,

```
         <c:choose>
          <c:when test="${varName eq condition}">
             <c:out value="${fn:substring(varName, 0, 3)}
          </c:when>
          <c:otherwise>
            ${varName}
          </c:otherwise>
         </c:choose>
```

so this prints the result as required ,and i have the scenario to use the same for other fields in the same page and also in other pages.

Is there way to reuse the jstl codes by passing the parameter to it . Something as we do for the methods in `Java` (write in a class and access it wherever needed) ?

Thanks in advance for your valuble answers and comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own custom JSP tags. With JSP 2.0, you can use [JSP tag files](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html), which have a syntax very similar to the JSP pages.

Create a subdirectory in the `WEB-INF` directory: `/WEB-INF/tags/mytaglib`

In this directory, create a file `displayVarName.tag`:

```
<%@ tag body-content="empty" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="c"   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="fn"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>

<%@ attribute name="varName"    rtexprvalue="true"  required="true" type="java.lang.String"  description="Description of varName" %> 
<%@ attribute name="condition"  rtexprvalue="true"  required="true" type="java.lang.String"  description="Description of condition" %> 

<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${varName eq condition}">
      <c:out value="${fn:substring(varName, 0, 3)}
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
      ${varName}
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Now you can import your tag and use it in your `JSP` page using:

```
<%@taglib prefix="mytaglib"   tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/mytaglib"%>

<mytaglib:displayVarName varName=${varName} condition=${condition} />
```

Comment: Thanks :) it worked as expected . Can you please point out the differences between the `tag` files and `.tld` files . Any references would be highly helpful

Comment: You use a `.tld` file when you developp your custom tags in `java`. There are some tutorials on the net for this, for example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm.